# Ajax filtering search - update variables / criteria

Tags: php, ajax, search, filter, symfony5

I'm doing a search by filter as you can search an article on amazon by applying some filters.

**Case 1:**
When I don't update the variable, it works, but the variables don't have the right value.

**Case 2:**
When I update the variables, they return the correct data only once.I don't put images of when I update the variables.

**Some images:**

When I load the page without any filter applied
[image]

Here is when I applied one filter, it returned the correct data, but variables are not updated.
[image]

The following image shows how the variable for the other criteria not updated (2 last images)[image]

Explanation of what I have done:
I have an Accession entity, its controller in which I returned the value, its twig in which I show the returned value and an ajax file in which I have the logic to which part to update.

When the page is loaded, I returned all the accessions

```
     public function search(allRepositoryNeeded, Request request){
        // get the filters selected by the user
        $selectedCountries = $request->get("countries");
        $selectedBiologicalStatuses = $request->get("biologicalStatuses");
        $selectedMLSStatuses = $request->get('mlsStatuses');
        $selectedTaxonomies = $request->get('taxonomies');
        if ($request->get('ajax')) {
           // filters
           $accessionsByCountry = $countryRepo->getAccessionsByCountry($selectedBiologicalStatuses);
           $accessionsByBiologicalStatus = $biologicalStatusRepo->getAccessionsByBiologicalStatus();
           
           // I have a new context and I used the "content" key in the ajax response returned
           $context = [
                'title' => 'Accession Filtered List',
                'accessions' => $filteredAccession,
                'accessionsByCountry' => $accessionsByCountry,
                'accessionsByBiologicalStatus' => $accessionsByBiologicalStatus,
            ];
           return new JsonResponse([
                'content' => $this->renderView('search/content_accession.html.twig', $context)
            ]);
        }
        $accessions =  $accessionRepo->findAll();
        $context = [
            'title' => 'Accession List',
            'accessions' => $accessions,
            // filters
            'accessionsByCountry' => $accessionsByCountry,
            'accessionsByBiologicalStatus' => $accessionsByBiologicalStatus,

        ];
        return $this->render('search/index_accession.html.twig', $context);
    }
```

Here, this is the ajax code.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    // get the filters form
    const filtersForm = document.querySelector("#filters");

    // get the inputs of the form filters
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#filters input");
    
    // add event listener on each input
    inputs.forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener("change", function() {
            // get the data of the form
            const form = new FormData(filtersForm);
            // create url string params
            const params = new URLSearchParams();
            // loop over the for
            form.forEach((value, key) => {
                params.append(key, value);
            });
            // get the current url
            const currentUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
            // get the ajax query ready
            // using fetch that return a promise
            // add "ajax = 1" so that the same index function in the controller can be used
            fetch(currentUrl.pathname + "?" + params.toString() + "&ajax=1", {
                headers: {
                    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
                }
            }).then(response => response.json()
            ).then(data => {
                // get the div id filtered_content which is to be replaced by the response data
                const filteredContent = document.querySelector("#filtered_content");
                // content key coming from the controller
                filteredContent.innerHTML = data.content;
            }).catch(e => alert(e));
        });
    });
})
```

And finally in the twig, I have and index file in which I returned all the data with a form whose id is **filters** for the list of the filters and the section I want to replaced by the data returned from the ajax call whose id is **filtered_content**

**Example of how I show the filters in the twigg**

```
   <ul class="list-group collapse" id="countryCollapse">
      {% for oneObj in accessionsByCountry %}
         <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
         <div>
             <input type="checkbox" name="countries[]" id="country{{ oneObj['country'].id }}" value="{{ oneObj['country'].id }}">
             <label for=country{{ oneObj['country'].id }}> {{ oneObj['country'].iso3 }} </label>
        </div>
        <span class="float-right badge badge-primary badge-pill">{{ oneObj['accQty'] }}</span>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

  // the div whose content is to be replaced.
  <div id="filtered_content">
     {% include "search/content_accession.html.twig" %}
  </div>
```

One idea I have is, instead of querying the function, query the last URL with the selected variables value on each new call / on each new filter applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I have found to do it so far is to update only the number in the badges on each AJAX call when the new returned number is greater than 0; when it's 0, just remove or hide the corresponding criteria / filter.

***What I have done is:***

**Step 1)**
Create a separate query in the repository which I call in the controller to return on each AJAX call a key pair value array of (ids => quantity) so that I can update the number in the badge for the right element (based on the unique id).

**Step 2)**
In the badge (in twig), add a id which I used to select the badge (in the JS code), add a data-id that contains the id (value coming from the db) of the criteria to check in step 3 if it's in the keys of the returned array in step 1.

**Step 3)**
In the JS, select all the elements of the corresponding criteria / filter based on the id defined in step 2. for each criteria, check if its id (the value of the data-id) is in the keys of the returned key pair value array; if so, add / or keep that criteria visible to the user and update the value of the badge, otherwise, hide the criteria in question.

```
            // country filter
            const filteredAccQty = document.querySelectorAll("#accQtyCountry");
            // accessionQtyCountry coming from the controller to update the number
            // display in the bagde. AccQtyTab is a key value data list [id => val]
            var accQtyTab = data.accessionQtyCountry;
            // get the badges to check which parent (objects) satifying the criteria or not.
            // loop over list of elements (badges...)
            // check if the data exists in the key value data array
            // for each data-id of the elements (each one).
            // if the data exists, update the badge value coming from the data array 
            // the object should be shown to the user
            // otherwise do not show the object(s) not satisfying the filters 
            filteredAccQty.forEach(element => {
                if (accQtyTab[element.getAttribute('data-id')]) {
                    element.innerHTML = accQtyTab[element.getAttribute('data-id')];
                    // important to add the d-flex class as removed when the object doesn't exist
                    element.parentElement.classList.add("d-flex");
                } else {
                    // important to remove the d-flex class as it's ovveriden the display none prop
                    // by some boostrap files
                    element.parentElement.classList.remove("d-flex");
                    element.parentElement.style.display = "none";
                }
            });
```